# moving rectangle using arrowkeys

Tags: java

i wrote the following code to move a rectangle using arrow keys but no sort of movement is occurring on the jframe window once i press the keys. I googled a lot regarding this but to no avail.I just see a rectangle drawn o the widow and nothing else. Kindly help
here is my code

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main 
{

    public static void main(String args[])
{

JFrame window=new JFrame();
    window.setSize(640,480);
    window.setTitle("window");
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    drawingComponent DC=new drawingComponent();
    window.add(DC);

}

}


import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Event;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.Timer;
public class drawingComponent extends JComponent implements ActionListener,KeyListener
{
    Timer t=new Timer(50,this);//moving after 5 milliseconds
int x=0,y=0,vx=0,vy=0;
    public drawingComponent()
    {

            t.start();
    addKeyListener(this);

    setFocusable(true);

    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);

}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{

    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D) g;
    Rectangle rect1=new Rectangle(x,y,100,30);
    g2.draw(rect1);

}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) //inbuilt fncn f actionListener(interface) which needs to be created
{
    x+=vx;      //changing values
    y+=vy;

    repaint();          //inbuilt fncn to repeat the paintComponent method
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{

    System.out.println("ewbkw");
    int code=e.getKeyCode();
    if(code==KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    { vx=0; vy=-2;repaint(); }
    if(code==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        { vx=0; vy=2; repaint(); }
    if(code==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        {vy=0; vx=-2; repaint(); }
    if(code==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {vy=0; vx=2; repaint();}
}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
{}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{}
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors? When I run your code, the rectangle moves. I press an arrow key, and the rectangle continuously moves in that direction.

Comment: I am not seeing any errors.When i run it, a stationary rectangle appears on the screen and no effect is seen when i press any arrow key

Comment: @edwin torres Do u mean to say that when u run the code,the rectangle is moving initially also without pressing any arrow key

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Your codes seems to work fine for me. Maybe try different arrow keys, or make sure your NUM lock is off.

Comment: When I run the code and press -> one time, the rectangle continuously moves to the right. When I press <- , the rectangle continuously moves to the left.

Comment: i have designed the code to do exactly what u r saying it is doing.But then, y is it not running on my pc?

Comment: Just a test: try without the timer.

Comment: @gliptal: no change is observed ......I hope u dnt mind if i ask u to run the above code....it wud b of gr8 help given the fact that its running fine on edwin torres' pc..........pls help

Comment: I have tried my code on eclipse,bluej and even command prompt ...still all i see is a stationary rectangle.....its really discouraging

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an `ArrayList` to add a key pressed to the `ArrayList` then delete it once it has been released.

Also you can use the

```
repaint();
```

after all your `if` Statements

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    System.out.println("ewbkw");

    int code = e.getKeyCode();

    if(code==KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        vx=0; vy=-2;
    }

    if(code==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        vx=0; vy=2;
    }

    if(code==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        vy=0; vx=-2;
    }

    if(code==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        vy=0; vx=2;
    }

    repaint();
}
```

If you are using only ONE statement for your `if` statements then you will not need to use Curly Brackets {}

```
if (true)
    System.out.println("Example of no brackets");
else
    System.out.println("Not even for an IF ELSE");
```

You also Might not NEED the Timer. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Are you sure curly brackets are unnecessary here? I'm not expert in Java, but in JavaScript and C++ that's not the case.

Comment: Yeah. They are only needed if you use more than one statement.
But i guess I didn't notice that this has 2 statements after each if statement so you may need the curly brackets in this specific method.
@YakovL